# $f$ locally (Lebesgue) integrable function on real line, $g(x):= \lim _{r\to \infty} \frac 1r \int_{x-r}^{x+r} f(t) dt$ exists for every real $x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, lebesgue-measure

Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a function such that $f \in L^1[-a,a] , \forall a \in (0,\infty)$ and $g(x) : = \lim _{r\to \infty} \dfrac 1r \int_{x-r}^{x+r} f(t) dt$ exists in $\mathbb R$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$ . Then is it true that $g$ is an affine map i.e. $g(x)-g(0)=x(g(1)- g (0)) , \forall x \in \mathbb R$ ?

Comment: (misread the question, sorry)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes. 
Let $\int_a^b:=\int_a^b f(t) dt$, with $\int_b^a:=-\int_a^b$ (if $a<b$). We have
\begin{equation}
 \int_{x-r}^{x+r}\sim rg(x)\tag{*}
\end{equation}
as $r\to\infty$, where $A\sim B$ is understood as $A-B=o(r)$, and $x,y,\dots$ are any real numbers. Hence, substituting $s:=r-x$, we have 
\begin{equation}
 \int_{-s}^{2x+s}\sim rg(x)\sim sg(x) 
\end{equation}
as $s\to\infty$. Comparing this with 
\begin{equation}
 \int_{-s}^{s}\sim sg(0), 
\end{equation}
we have 
\begin{equation}
 \int_{s}^{2x+s}\sim s(g(x)-g(0)) 
\end{equation}
for $s\to\infty$ -- and then similarly for $s\to-\infty$. 
Hence, 
\begin{equation}
 \int_{y-r}^{y+r}-\int_{x-r}^{x+r}=\int_{x+r}^{y+r}-\int_{x-r}^{y-r}
 \sim2r(g(\tfrac{y-x}2)-g(0))
\end{equation}
as $r\to\infty$. 
Also, by $(*)$, 
\begin{equation}
 \int_{y-r}^{y+r}-\int_{x-r}^{x+r}
 \sim r(g(y)-g(x)). 
\end{equation}
So, 
\begin{equation}
 g(y)-g(x)=2[g(\tfrac{y-x}2)-g(0)] \tag{**}
\end{equation}
for all real $x,y$. Since $g$ is measurable, this implies that it is affine -- see details in the edit below.

**Edit:** Willie Wong offered a strengthening of the above argument, which yields the Cauchy functional equation, from which the result easily follows.

I would like to show how to use just the functional equation $(**)$ to get the same result. 
The reasoning is quite similar to that for the Cauchy functional equation; cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359183/measurable-cauchy-function-is-continuous). 
Indeed, rewrite $(**)$ as 
\begin{equation}
 h(y)-h(x)=2h(\tfrac{y-x}2) \tag{***}
\end{equation}
for all real $x,y$, where $h:=g-g(0)$. 
Since $h(0)=0$ and $h(y)-h(x)$ depends on $x$ and $y$ only via $y-x$, it easily follows that $h(x)=h(1)x$ for all rational $x$.

It remains to show that $h$ is continuous. In view of $(***)$, it is enough to verify that $h$ is continuous at $0$. Take any neighborhood $U$ of $0$, and then let $V$ be any neighborhood of $0$ such that $\frac12\,(V-V)\subseteq U$. The union of the sets $h^{-1}(x+V)$ over all rational $x$ is $\mathbb R$. So, for some rational $q$ the set $W:=h^{-1}(q+V)$ is of positive Lebesgue measure. Therefore, $W-W$ is a neighborhood of $0$. By $(***)$, 
for any $x,y$ in $W$, we have $h(\tfrac{y-x}2)=\frac12\,(h(y)-h(x))\in\frac12\,[(q+V)-(q+V)]=\frac12\,(V-V)\subseteq U$, so that 
$h(\frac12\,(W-W))\subseteq U$. Since $W-W$ is a neighborhood of $0$, the result follows.

Comment: How did you get $\int_{y-r}^{y+r}-\int_{x-r}^{x+r}=\int_{y+r}^{x+r}-\int_{y-r}^{x-r}$ ?

Comment: That was a typo: $x$ and $y$ on the right side has to be interchanged. This is now fixed.

Comment: There was a typo in my previous comment as well: I wanted to say "had to be interchanged". :-)

Comment: Your argument for the key estimate $$ \int_s^{s+2x} \sim s(g(x) - g(0))$$ also implies for every $\alpha\in [-1,1]$ that $$ \int_{-s}^{-s + (1-\alpha)x} + \int_s^{s + (1+\alpha)x} \sim s(g(x) - g(0)) $$ which together imply directly $$ g(\frac{1-\alpha}2 x) - g(0) + g(\frac{1 + \alpha}{2} x) - g(0) = g(x) - g(0) $$ for every $\alpha\in [-1,1]$ and every $x$, which is precisely the statement that $g$ is affine (without appealing to measurability).

Comment: @WillieWong : Thank you for your comment. However, I don't understand how you got your 2nd displayed formula: to get $\sim sg(x)$, one needs to have an interval of length $\sim2s$ centered at $x$, and I don't see it there. Also, your 3rd displayed formula will follow from the  functional equation $h(x+y)=h(x)+h(y)$ for all $x,y$, where $h(x):=g(x)-g(0)$ -- but I don't even know how to a get the nice solution of this functional equation for $h$ without assuming that $h$ is measurable.

Comment: About Cauchy's functional equation: yes, you are right. I wasn't thinking straight. (I was thinking of the difference between convexity and midpoint convexity which obviously is not the point here.) For the displayed formula: set $s = r - \alpha x$ then $$ sg(x) \sim rg(x) \sim \int_{x - r}^{x+r} = \int_{x - s - \alpha x}^{x + s +\alpha x} $$ and then proceed as what you wrote.

Comment: I still don't understand your 2nd display. There, you have $F(-s+(1-\alpha)x)+F(s+(1+\alpha)x)=F(x-s-\alpha x)+F(x+s+\alpha x)$, where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ -- whereas in your 4th display you have $-F(x-s-\alpha x)+F(x+s+\alpha x)$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: ah! Sorry, I missed a minus sign in front of the first term in the second display when I transcribed from paper. But the third displayed equation is the same: the corrected version of the second displayed equation implies in  particular $$ - \int_{-s}^{-s + 2x} \sim s[ g(x) - g(0)] $$ which you can use to get the third one.

Comment: @WillieWong : It seems all good now. :-) Also, I think the restriction $\alpha\in[-1,1]$ is not needed, the way $\int_a^b$ was defined for $b<a$ in the beginning of my answer -- so that you can get the bona fide Cauchy functional equation, for $h=g-g(0)$.

Comment: I have completed the answer by completely solving the functional equation.

Answer (score -1):

No, consider the function which takes the value 0 for negative x, and the value 1 for non-negativ x.

Comment: In this case $g(x) \equiv \frac12$, and is affine.

Comment: Ups, I also misread the question.

Comment: You're not the only one it seems.